# Application works in cmd, gives segfault in git bash

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, segmentation-fault, git-bash

I'm working on a C++ application in Visual Studio 2015 Community using CGAL. The application works when I run it from Visual Studio (both in debug and release mode, with and without the debugger attached) or from Windows command prompt. However, when running the exact same executable with the same arguments from git bash (mintty 2.0.3 x86-64-pc-msys), I sometimes get a segmentation fault in a call to a dll. This is frustrating for me, as I normally use git bash as my console on Windows.

The error occurs when I construct a CORE::Expr (an exact number type) from a string, e.g. "726838724295606890549323807888004534353641360687318060281490199180639288113397923326191050713763565560762521606266177933534601628614656". This calls CGAL_Core-vc140-mt-gd-4.8.dll, which in turn calls libgmp-10.dll, which is where the segmentation fault occurs.

Is it possible that there is a programming error which doesn't get exposed in Windows command prompt, or can the use of a different console cause a segmentation fault?

Comment: Try http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to see which DLLs the application wants to use

Comment: "in a call to a dll" - if you know the approximate location of the crash, please post some code because it's a very vague question without more information.

Comment: Stack/memory corruption.

Comment: @TamásSzelei I've added some context related to the error. My question relates more to whether using a different console can cause segmentation faults though. At this point I'm trying to figure out whether there is even a programming error to solve.

Comment: Of course there is a programming error on your side. If it runs sometimes and sometimers not, it is most certainly not the environment. There MIGHT be a problem in the library, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: @Devolus: well, it turns out that the problem _was_ caused by the terminal I was running it in.

Comment: Well, that can happen of course, but there are so many newbies here, claiming that everything else but there code is wrong, that I would look there first. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that git bash was loading libgmp-10.dll from its own install directory (Git/mingw64/bin/libgmp-10.dll) rather than from the CGAL bin directory.